# Check if a field exists in an object in js_of_ocaml

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

In my `wrap.ml`, I have a function as follows:

```
  Js.Unsafe.global##.test := Js.wrap_callback (
    fun params -> 
      print_endline "params##.a:";
      print_endline (Js.to_string params##.a);
      print_endline "params##.b:";
      print_endline (Js.to_string params##.b);
      Js.string ((Js.to_string params##.a) ^ (Js.to_string params##.b))
  );
```

As a result, in a JavaScript file, I could call e.g., `test({a: "abc", b:"efg"})`.

I would like to know in the OCaml file, is there a way to check if the field `b` exists in the object `params`, before evaluating `Js.to_string params##.b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see how to do this at the bottom of this page:

> https://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/latest/manual/bindings

For this code:

```
let () =
    if Js.Optdef.test ((Js.Unsafe.coerce Dom_html.document)##.URL) then
        Printf.printf "document.URL exists\n"
    else
        Printf.printf "document.URL does not exist\n";
    if Js.Optdef.test ((Js.Unsafe.coerce Dom_html.document)##.XXX) then
        Printf.printf "document.XXX exists\n"
    else
        Printf.printf "document.XXX does not exist\n";
```

I see the following on the Javascript console:

```
document.URL exists
document.XXX does not exist
```